# Why does Yourkit 8.X is recommended to profile only java 5 applications?

Tags: java, profiler, yourkit

When upgrading yourkit profiler I've noticed the following message at their web site:

> YourKit Java Profiler 8.0.30
>
> Use version 8.0 to profile Java 5
>   applications only. To profile Java 6
>   and Java 7 applications, use version
>   9.5.

The thing I cannot understand is why do they recommend to profile **only** Java 5 applications with 8.0? Is there any rationale behind this or just marketing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a *guess*, new APIs were added to Java 6 which allow version 9.5 to work more efficiently or effectively. That would certainly make sense of the message.

EDIT: This is confirmed on the [Yourkit 9.0 changes page](http://www.yourkit.com/changes/index90.jsp):

> Caveat: only applications running on Java 6 or newer can be profiled. New functionality provided by this version of the profiler requires Java 6 APIs which are not available in earlier Java versions. For profiling Java 5 applications, please use YourKit Java Profiler 8.0.

Comment: are you confirming my guess that it is possible to profile any java applications with Yourkit 8. The only thing you will miss are some features (important?) which are possible with Yourkit 9 when profiling java 6 applications?

Comment: @Alex: I wouldn't so far as claiming that's definitely true, but it sounds like it's *probable*. Worth a try, at least.

Answer (score 0):

I have profiled java 6 applications with Yourkit 7.5 and it worked well.

Have seen some small bugs - GC time is not always correct, in CPU profiling sampling mode there are Object.wait methods that are not supposed to consume CPU.